# Swift - UITableView scroll to bottom is slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

### Problem

scrolling to the bottom of table view is slow 
the table view contains about 25 items
and there is a bit of complexity in creating each cell
so creating 25 of them at the same time takes about 200 ms(believe me there is no way I can make it any more optimized)

### Soloutions I've tried

there are basically two options for scrolling to bottom of table view(And I have searched the entire stack over flow for this)

1. `tableView.scrollRectToVisible`   OR  `tableView.setContentOffset`
2. `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath`

the problem with the first option is, although it is pretty fast and it doesn't recreate every cell in the way from top to bottom of tableView, I need to call a new main queue to get it to work. if I call it in the same queue as the one that called `tableView.reloadData()`, then there will be a strange lag when scrolling the tableview(logs show that lots of cells are being re created unnecessarily, and I mean lots of them). and let me add that both threads are main thread. but still I must call the `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to get rid of that awkward lag. however new main thread adds a good delay to the initial load.
here is my code:

```
func loadData(groupID: String){
    self._chats = self._cache[groupID]!
    _tableView.reloadData()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: self._tableView.contentSize.height - self._tableView.bounds.height, width: self._tableView.contentSize.width, height: self._tableView.bounds.height)
        self._tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
    }
}
```

again if I don't use the dispatch_get_main_queue() the tableView would be supper laggy. and if I do use it, then there will be about 100 ms delay in execution which makes the initial loading slow.

the second option is slow too, cause scrolling to the last indexPath means creating every cell in the way. and that cannot happen in the background and doing it in the main thread means freezing the UI for about 200 ms.

can you suggest any other solution or find something wrong with what I'm doing? I've tried every thing and still tableView isn't fast enough.

Comment: `believe me there is no way I can make it any more optimised` - only if you prove that to us...

Comment: why are you reloading the table view and then wanting to scroll to the bottom?

Comment: @Wain it's a messaging app and every message bubble has lots of details like date, user thumbnail and more. it's pretty complex and I tried making it more optimized but haven't had much luck.

Comment: @Wain is there a way to scroll to bottom then add the items? wouldn't that take me back to the top position?

Comment: so you should probably ask your question about that, and show the code. why are you fully reloading the table?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman I am reusing the cells. but the process of adjusting the cell based on the corresponding model is complex. there are constraints and other stuff that need adjustment

Comment: go for reload particular cell and uses reusable property for optimisation

Comment: @Wain when you go to group in whatsapp for example. the cells of the group are created then scrolled to bottom, right? that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Wain do you have time to talk about this in chat room?

Comment: you don't seem to understand, the question is why you're calling `reloadData` and the ask is for you to show the code which configures the cell. this is not a scrolling problem, it's a data loading and cell config problem, probably related to image management, but we can't tell until you show us what you're doing

Comment: @Wain no I get it, I'm using reloadData to get the items on the table. is there any other way? the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath is about 200 lines do you really wan't to see that? cause I think no matter how much time  is spent to adjust a cell, still moving to the last cell shouldn't re create every cell in the way

Comment: @MohsenShakiba I would suggest then to update model correctly rather than scrolling to last cell just to load all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time Profiler one of Xcode Instruments to understand on which of your processes your app stack.